# SehhdzEu6O folder in Home directory

Tags: home-directory, desktop-directories

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I got extra folder "SehhdzEu6O" in my home directory, contents 3,86,797 items, totalling 0 bytes. Please help me, i want to know which applications create this folder and is ti safe to delete.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -lh ~/SehhdzEu6O/` to your question (in case of large output just add the first 10-15 lines truncating the rest).

Answer (score 1):

*Don't panic*, it's only a little problem, follow my instructions to solve.
It can be a temporary folder, created by an application or by a user script.
It can also be a collateral result of data corruption, check the `LOST+FOUND` directory in the root of the mounted filesystem if your hardware lacks a *group of continuity with long-lasting batteries*.
In those cases you can safely delete it.

Do the following:

1. **ask if the administrator or another user created the directory and why**, if nobody knows, proceed;
2. login with the user owning the `SehhdzEu6O` directory (you);
3. start a terminal (`xTerm` or `Terminal` are both fine), type `cd` and press `ENTER`/`RETURN`;
4. type `ls -l -h --author SehhdzEu6O | less` and press `ENTER`/`RETURN` to obtain a list of files contained in the directory (use the arrows to move and `q` to exit);
5. type `mount` and press `ENTER`/`RETURN`: verify that the directory isn't a mount point and, if it **is** a mount point, don't proceed;
6. **if the files in the directory are clearly useless** (and not created by root or another user, you can see the file list), type

   `rm --preserve-root -d -r SehhdzEu6O`

   in the new window and press ENTER/RETURN. The directory and any file contained should disappear.

Contact your system administrator to report the event, if the system is not yours.
Please, feel free to comment under here if your have more questions and don't forget to press the left UP arrow if I'm of any help.
Have a nice day.